# How to Add Item Toolbar In ReportView C#

Tags: winforms

After printing in the report, I want to update the data of a table with column 'Print' to 'Y', otherwise print 'N'.

After printing in the report, I want to update the data of a table with column 'Print' to 'Y', otherwise print 'N'.

Comment: Did you run into a specific problem when you tried to do this? Can you please add some debugging details that would help someone reproduce your issue? For example, you could [[**Edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75633770/edit)] your question and add a thumbnail screenshot of the table, or do a mockup in `Paint` of how you want the item toolbar to look. It would help to see a minimal sample of your code for the report view and know for sure if this is `ReportViewer` class or something else. Thx!

Comment: [Add Custom Button To ReportViewer Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32327499/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateStripButton(ReportViewer ReportViewer, EventHandler Print_Click, string ToolTip, int Itemindex, Image img)
    {
        ToolStrip toolStrip = (ToolStrip)ReportViewer.Controls.Find("toolStrip1", true)[0];
        ToolStripButton btn = new ToolStripButton();
        btn.Image = img;
        btn.ToolTipText = ToolTip;
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(Print_Click);
        toolStrip.Items.Insert(Itemindex, btn);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).